# What's the difference between "$\to$" (implication) and "$\vdash$" (therefore)?

Tags: logic, notation

In Wikipedia, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system) in the last axiom of the Natural deduction system, it says "From [accepting $p$ allows a proof of $q$], infer $(p \to q)$." Isn't that a tautology? In the big table "Basic and Derived Argument Forms" that follows, I see it using a new symbol "$\vdash$" to express "therefore". Isn't that something can be done by the symbol "$\to$"? For example, what's the difference between "$(p \land q) \vdash p$" and "$(p \land q) \to p$"?

An interesting symbolic representation of the last axiom of NDS is that $(p \vdash q) \vdash (\vdash p \to q)$. Which I don't understand why is made so complicated.

---

What also puzzles me is in the ["example of a proof"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_of_a_proof) that follows. Since you list "$A$" as a promise, which is basically saying "assuming $A=\text{True}$", then why you have to go around such a big circle, using disjunction, conjunction, and conjunction elimination to prove back that "$A$" is true? If it is me, I would say "assuming $A=\text{True}$, we will know that $A=\text{true}$. Bang! Now we get $A \vdash A$, so we have $\vdash A \to A$." What's wrong in this deduction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implies ($\Rightarrow$) vs. Entails ($\models$) vs. Provable ($\vdash$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-rightarrow-vs-entails-models-vs-provable-vdash)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$(p \land q) \to p$ is a sentence in propositional calculus. When $p$ and $q$ are assigned truth values, that sentence always gets the value *true*, that is, is a tautology.

$(p \land q) \vdash p$ is a statement in a *metalanguage* about propositional calculus. It says that $p$ can be deduced from $p \land q$ according to whatever deduction rules are valid.

Comment: If that is the case, I think the shape of the symbol "$\to$" is highly deceptive, because actually it is just an operation, no more special than other operations like "$\land$" or "$\lor$", and is not the synonym of "implication", because using it won't ensure the implicational relationship exist.

Comment: Thus: some elementary logic texts use "if, then" for $\rightarrow$ and avoid using "implies".  Others may use two different symbols $\rightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ for these two things.

Comment: I thought a sentence was a formula with no free variables. But in $(p \land q) \rightarrow p$ all variables are free.

Comment: Voldemort, as outlined in your question there's a close relationship between the material conditional and the provability relation. The [deduction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) shows that if from $P$ we can prove $Q$, then we may legitimately infer the conditional statement $P \rightarrow Q$. Taking $P \rightarrow Q$ to be synonymous with $P \vdash Q$ is an error, but not a particularly egregious one since we can move between them seamlessly in most contexts.

Comment: Matt, $p$ and $q$ in the question are meant to denote propositions, i.e. atoms of the propositional calculus, not variables in the predicate calculus.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh: Now I see it this way: "$\to$" is a binary operation sitting next to "$\land$" and "$\lor$", just one with a "curious" truth table. Why it is curious? Because *somehow* the result of "$p \to q$" is always true when $q$ can be logically deduced by $p$!

Comment: And please also help me with the second question I've asked!

Comment: @Voldemort: yes, that's a fine way to view the material conditional. Its strange truth table has long been a subject of dispute amongst philosophers of logic, and students often find it confusing when it's first introduced. It may help to think of it in terms of the equivalent statement, $\lnot{}P \vee Q$ (classical logic is often formulated with only negation and conjunction or disjunction, as the other connectives can be introduced merely as abbreviations).

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh Thanks for clarifying! Btw, unless you use '@', I don't get notified.

Comment: @Matt, thanks, I wasn't aware of that subtlety.

Answer (score 12):

The connection between the material conditional and provability is an important one, and very intuitive once the basic definitions are understood. In a formal proof we assume a set of premises and derive a particular conclusion. Let's call the set of premises $\Gamma$ and the conclusion $\psi$. Now suppose we want to prove $\varphi$, but our premises are too weak to prove it by themselves. So we additionally assume $\theta$, and manage to derive $\varphi$. We represent this symbolically by saying that $\Gamma \cup \left\{\theta\right\} \vdash \varphi$.

Contrast this with a *conditional statement*, like the following: *if* $x + y < z$, *then* $x < z \wedge y < z$ (for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$). We can formalise this in the predicate calculus using the [material conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional): $\forall{x}\forall{y}\forall{z} (x + y < z \rightarrow x < z \wedge y < z)$.

The [deduction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) states that given $\Gamma \cup \left\{\theta\right\} \vdash \varphi$, we can assert that our initial set of premises $\Gamma$ proves the conditional statement $\theta \rightarrow \varphi$. Formally, $(\Gamma \cup \left\{\theta\right\} \vdash \varphi) \vdash (\Gamma \vdash \theta \rightarrow \varphi)$, which is just a slightly more general version of the conditional proof rule $(p \vdash q) \vdash (\vdash p \rightarrow q)$.

It's important to bear in mind the distinction here between the *object language*, which is the language in which the premises, conclusion and all steps of the proof are stated, and the *metalanguage* which lets us make assertions about what can be proved from what. $\rightarrow$ is a symbol of the object language, which informally corresponds to the *if...then* locution in English. $\vdash$ is a symbol of the metalanguage, and corresponds to provability: from these premises, this conclusion can be derived. The importance of the deduction theorem is that it shows a way for us to move from statements of the metalanguage to statements of the object language.

---

Here's an updated answer to your second question, having looked at the link page for more than a second. The example proof is complicated just so they can show a chain of reasoning with steps between the initial assumption and the derivation of $A \vdash A$.

1. $A$ (Assumption)
2. $A$ (From 1)
3. $A \vdash A$ (From 1 and 2)
4. $\vdash A \rightarrow A$ (From 3 by CP)

So far, so obvious. And of course by simply inspecting the truth table for $A \rightarrow A$ we can see that it's a tautology; this is the *semantic* approach, while the derivation shown on the Wikipedia page is a *syntactic* approach.

The problem with the truth table approach is that it doesn't scale to first-order logic: what's the truth table for $\forall{x} \; P(x)$? Assuming we assigned constants to every element of the domain, we could posit some kind of analogue for a truth table, but if the domain were infinite then the truth table would be infinitely wide! This is why semantics for first-order logic are given by [model theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Semantics), not truth tables. However, the deduction theorem still holds in first-order logic (for closed formulae).

Comment: Thank you. Except that I think to prove "$A \to A$" means to prove that the  proposition "$A \to A$" can be derived from *nothing* (not $A$). And in order to prove so we should prove that "$A \vdash A$". I think this is important because not only "$A \to A$" is a theorem when $A$ is a theorem, but also when $\neg A$ is a theorem. And the importance of the deduction theorem is it points out that, if "$p \vdash q$", then "$p \to q$" can be deduced, regardless of whether $p$ is or is not a theorem.

Comment: I must admit, I answered this in a bit of a hurry and didn't read the Wikipedia proof too carefully. You're quite right; I have amended my answer to reflect this. Do let me know if anything is still unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Talk of the 'metalanguage' can be a little confusing in my opinion, so maybe an order-theoretic perspective would be clearer? In particular, let $P$ denote a [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra). Consider $p,q \in P$. Then:

- $p \wedge q \leq p$ is simply true.
- $(p \wedge q) \rightarrow p$ is an element of $P$.
- That element happens to equal $1$.

Furthermore, $\vdash$ is a bit like $\leq$, except you can have multiple inputs on the left. For example, we could define:

> **Definition.** A *multiposet* is a thin multicategory.
>
> We write $x_0,\ldots, x_{n-1} \vdash y$ to mean that there exists a multiarrow $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1} \rightarrow y$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what got pointed out in the other comments, (p∧q)→p, once we write exactly what the author means, that is ((p∧q)→p), we have a well-formed formula (or formula or statement form).  On the other hand, ((p∧q)⊢p) is not a well-formed formula, as it doesn't follow the formation rules of some language, or at least needs a set of formation rules distinct from that of ((p∧q)→p) as it exists in the metalanguage, not the object language.