# discrete math: is there a difference between $\subseteq$ to $\supseteq$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a question which asks if $X \supseteq I$.
Is it just the same as $I \subseteq X$?

Because I never saw it the other way around or learned about it, I'm confused.

Comment: yes it is. {}{}

Comment: It's the exact same. Sometimes this is done only to make a sentence flow better but it's completely avoidable if your sentence is framed properly.

Comment: Sometimes it appears in constructions like "let $x\in U\supseteq V$"

Comment: There is perhaps one caveat to be aware of. Some mathematical logic texts (usually older ones) use the symbol $\supset$ as alternative symbol for logical implication.

Comment: The usage as a notation for implication (see the comment by @DavidH) has also been mentioned in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391217/using-p-supset-q-instead-of-p-implies-q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking from mookid, so we have an answer, yes.

Comment: Yes to "is there a difference between $\subseteq$ to $\supseteq$" or yes to "Is $X \supseteq I$ just the same as $I \subseteq X$"? :)

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia article about [subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) says:

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets and every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, then:
>
> - $A$ is a *subset* of (or is included in) $B$, denoted by $A \subseteq B$,
>
> or equivalently
>
> - $B$ is a *superset* of (or includes) $A$, denoted by $B \supseteq A$.

Comment: thanks, I flaged and asked for it to be deleted.

Comment: I do not see any reason why this question should be deleted.