# Name of this rule: $a \vdash b$ and $b \vdash c$ then $a \vdash c$?

Tags: first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to provide names of meta-theorems at each stage in my proof, and I forgot the name of the rule that says $a \vdash b$ and $b \vdash c$ then $a \vdash c$.  Does anyone know?

Comment: I looked through my textbook but couldn't find it.

Comment: I think it is transitive.

Comment: The symbol is called [Turnstile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implies vs. Entails vs. Provable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-vs-entails-vs-provable)

Comment: This isn't a concept question - I'm just looking for the name of this rule.  Seems like transitive might be correct.

Comment: It can be called [Hypothetical syllogism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It express the transitivity of the *deducibility* relation.

We may compare it with the "principle of the syllogism" in Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, [Principia Mathematica](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA99) (2nd ed - 1927).

And also with the "propositional version" of the argument form called [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism).