# I'm not familiar with this symbol, how to parse it?

Tags: logic, notation

In the context of propositional logic I've encountered this $|=$ symbol that I'm not familiar with. What does it mean? Does it behave like an implication?

Here's where I found it.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols last line in table

Comment: It's called a double turnstile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_turnstile

Comment: Also helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286077/215011

Comment: I think a collection of these constitute the perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: BTW you can type it as $\models$ `$\models$` or $\vDash$.`$\vDash$`.

Comment: The symbol means [Tautological consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_consequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are sentences of propositional logic, $\varphi\vDash\psi$ means that the sentence $\varphi\to\psi$ is true under any assignment of truth values to the propositional variables occurring in $\varphi$ and $\psi$. In your question there are no propositional variables to which truth values can be assigned, so the question is in effect asking which of the following sentences are true:

- $\text{False}\to\text{True}$
- $\text{True}\to\text{False}$