# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are propositional statements. Show that $X \implies Y$ holds if and only if $X \rightarrow Y$ is a tautology.

Tags: logic

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are propositional statements. Show that $X \implies Y$ holds if and only if $X \rightarrow Y$ is a tautology.

If $X \rightarrow B $ is a tautology, then this means that it’s always true. So the value of the $\rightarrow $ connective is always $1$ in the truth table. Could I have some hints on how is one supposed to use this to show the statement $X \implies Y$?

Comment: It means that the case when $X$ is True and $Y$ is False is ruled out. What does it means in terms of entailment?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286077/implies-rightarrow-vs-entails-models-vs-provable-vdash)

Comment: See [Tautological consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautological_consequence) for an helpful review of the basic definition.

Comment: You're well on your way!  Can you add the definition of $\implies$ to your post?

Comment: Bram's point is pertinent: if $\implies$ is defined more weakly than as entailment (logical implication), then $X\implies Y$ holds if (but **not** automatically only if) $X\to Y$ is a tautology.